# Python - Open file in default program and save with default program extension (or the like)

Tags: python, excel, xml

I'm currently trying to do the following:

1. Open up an .xml file that's already in spreadsheet format with Excel
2. Save the .xml file as .xlsx without corrupting the file

Other options that I can take via Python are:

1. Convert the .xml to .xlsx
2. Copy specific columns (A1:AC6000) to another Excel workbook
3. Import an XML file directly in an Excel workbook.

I failed at all of them and can't think of a different way so here I am asking for help. My latest code is here:

```py
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl;

# opening the source excel file
file = 'C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\HESKlogin\\Downloads\\data.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(file)
ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']

# opening the destination excel file
filename1 = 'C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\HESKlogin\\Downloads\\updated.xlsx'
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']

# calculate total number of rows and
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

# copying the cell values from source
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
# saving the destination excel file

wb2.save(filename1)
```

I also tried changing the format of the file which ultimately corrupted the file:

```
A = r"C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\HESKlogin\\Downloads\\data.xml"
pre, ext = os.path.splitext(A)
B = os.rename(A, pre + ".xlsx")
```

I tried importing the file into Excel which was terrible since none of the data in xml have properly name attributes to differentiate the data. I also tried calling a macro, but I get an error with each macro on my network, so I disposed of that alternative.

Any assistance you can give would be much appreciated! I also think it's important to say that I'm a noob.

Comment: If you use `r'...'`you don't need the escaping   `\\\` in the path name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :)

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32    
import requests as r
import pandas as pd


hesk = "C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\TEST\\hesk.xml"
folder = "C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\TEST"
output = "C:\\Users\\ddejean\\Desktop\\TEST\\output.csv"


cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(folder))

xmlfile = os.path.join(cd, hesk)
csvfile = os.path.join(cd, output)

# EXCEL COM TO SAVE EXCEL XML AS CSV
if os.path.exists(csvfile):
    os.remove(csvfile)

try:
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.OpenXML(xmlfile)
    wb.SaveAs(csvfile, 6)
    wb.Close(True)    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)    
finally:
    # RELEASES RESOURCES
    wb = None
    excel = None
```